# Fatal error: Call to undefined function menu_execute_active_handler() in drupal 7.9

Tags: drupal-7

I am in problem, my site is down.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function menu_execute_active_handler()

in drupal.

please help me.

Comment: Is the `menu_execute_active_handler()` method defined? Because I suspect that is all anybody can suggest based on the **very** limited information you have given. Please edit your question to include a lot more detail.

Answer (score 0):

As this function is part of the essential codebase, inside includes/menu.inc, please check the integrity of the source code of Drupal.

Apart from that, Drupal 7.9 is a very old, insecure release. If the security updates were not applied, almost certainly the site is hacked.
Check this page: https://www.drupal.org/drupalsa05FAQ

If all these do not help, install XDebug PHP extension (http://xdebug.org/) and check the execution profile, also with XDebug you can get stacktrace-included errors, that can help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue many times. You can check your settngs.php where memcache setup or not if yes then check its correct ?

If you comment your memcache code it will work perfectly so here I can see issue of memacache.